# javascript split / join character within quotes

Tags: javascript, split

I have some text and need to replace all instances of a character within quotes `" z6 "` and replace with `" / "`
I'm not sure how to include quotes within quotes:

```
text = text.split("" z6 "").join("" / "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape using backslash

```
text = text.split("\" z6 \"").join("\" / \"");
```

Or template strings:

```
text = text.split(`" z6 "`).join(`" / "`);
```

Or single quotes

```
text = text.split('" z6 "').join('" / "');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes and double quotes interchangeably. To solve your specific problem:

```js
text = text.split('" z6 "').join('" / "');
```